# First embedded ImageView in ScrollView not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-imageview

I have a `ScrollView` with a `LinearLayout` and inside 4 `ImageView`'s but the first one is not shown.

(The names of drawables and id's are NOT the same, I wrote XXX intentionally)

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linLayoutAbout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    // Another stuff
    ...  
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView   
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:isScrollContainer="true" >  
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linLayoutScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >    

                <ImageView             //<- Just this ImageView is not shown
                    android:id="@+id/logo_XXX"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_XXX" />

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/logo_XXX"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo_XXX" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo_XXX"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_XXX" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo_XXX"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_XXX" />
            </LinearLayout>                                          
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout> 


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/close_about" />
```

If I set `android:layout_height` with some dp_value then I can't see the first `ImageView`, but If I set it with "wrap_content", then I can see all `ImageView`'s.

May anyone tell me what I do wrong and how can I solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the line

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

in the LinearLayout with id "@+id/linLayoutScrollView1" inside the ScrollView. Because it centers the linear layout within those 65 pixels of the ScrollView, which means half of the images above are gone out of the screen.

Try this code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linLayoutAbout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    // Another stuff
    ...  


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:isScrollContainer="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linLayoutScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo_XXX1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo_XXX2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo_XXX3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo_XXX4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="close_about" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I changed that LinearLayout and added some real values to the images. Now all the images show up properly. Just replace with your images and see the difference.

Comment: It has not worked. I tried all possible combinations, with and without gravity in scrollview and in LinearLayout.

Comment: It already worked with first answer (before editing), I have run the old one. Thx ;) But many thanks, that you made such an example.

Answer (score 0):

65 must be smaller than the total height. It must show when you try a larger  dp value, maybe 150 etc. It worked some random images I tried.

Comment: I got the low half of first ImageView. My intention with this "65dp" was to create a scrollable "window" (ScrollView with a determinated height) on which I can show iamges. If I increase the height I show of course the first ImageView (as said) but I want to scroll and view the images over this "window".  Regards

Comment: That was irrelevant, it was `gravity` of LinearLayour. Thx